# Assigning instances of objects to an array

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, java-io

I am using `bufferedFileReader` and `lineScanner` to read through a `csv` file, delimiting at commas and assigning the first token in the line to an object of class `Team`. Each token after this is assigned to a variable of `Team`.

I have this part working fine. The next part is to place these objects into an Array, which I have no idea how to do. I am assuming that I need to place some more code at the bottom of my while loop (maybe a for loop) but I am not sure.

Code for the class is:

```
public class Pool
{
   /* instance variables */
   private String poolName; // the name of the pool
   private Team[] teams;    // the teams in the pool
   private final static int NOOFTEAMS = 5; // number of teams in each pool

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Pool
    */
   public Pool(String aName)
   {
      super();
      this.poolName = aName;
      this.teams = new Team[NOOFTEAMS];
   }

  /**
    * Prompts the user for the name of the text file that 
    * contains the results of the teams in this pool. The
    * method uses this file to set the results of the teams.
    */
   public void loadTeams()
   {
      String fileName;
      OUDialog.alert("Select input file for " + this.getPoolName());
      fileName = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
      File aFile = new File(fileName);
      BufferedReader bufferedFileReader = null;

      try
      {
         Scanner lineScanner;
         bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
         String correctPool = bufferedFileReader.readLine();

         if (!poolName.equals(correctPool))
         {
           OUDialog.alert("Wrong File Selected");           
         }
         else
         {
            String currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
            while (currentLine != null)
            {
               lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine); 
               lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
               Team aTeam = new Team(lineScanner.next());
               aTeam.setWon(lineScanner.nextInt());
               aTeam.setDrawn(lineScanner.nextInt());
               aTeam.setLost(lineScanner.nextInt());
               aTeam.setFourOrMoreTries(lineScanner.nextInt());
               aTeam.setSevenPointsOrLess(lineScanner.nextInt());
               currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
               aTeam.setTotalPoints(aTeam.calculateTotalPoints());
               //somewhere here I need to add the aTeam object to the array

             }
      }
```

Comment: `teams[someCounter++] = aTeam;`?

Comment: What does `super()` do if `Pool` doesn't extend anything?

Comment: @moarCoffee Everything extends something, except `Object`. So it calls the parent constructor just like normal

Comment: @Jyr something like  'List<Team> = new ArrayList<>();' before the while loop and then 'ArrayListName.add(aTeam);?' at the end of the while loop?

Comment: Initialize a variable (`someCounter`) to 0 and do what @DaveNewton suggests.

Comment: You can use @DaveNewton his suggestion. I initially didn't see the `teams` array in your code. But if you don't know the amount of teams, you could still go with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Kon I think the question was more of a "Why are you calling `super` explicitly since `Pool` doesn't extend anything?", e.g., it wasn't a request for the mechanism behind inheritance and constructors.

Comment: @DaveNewton Granted I likely misunderstood, but then why not simply ask "why call `super()` explicitly [regardless of the class, since it is always implicit regardless of type hierarchy]"?

Comment: @Kon Too many words, probably :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Pool
{  
    private int teamCounter;
    ...

    public Pool(String aName)
    {
        super();
        this.poolName = aName;
        this.teams = new Team[NOOFTEAMS];
        teamCounter=0;
    }

    ...

    public void loadTeams()
    {
        ...
        //somewhere here I need to add the aTeam object to the array
        this.teams[teamCounter++]=aTeam;

    }
}
```

Comment: `teamCounter` needs to be initialised in `loadTeams()`, not the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your attributes:

```
private List<Team> myTeam=new ArrayList<Team>();
```

then in your loop add this line at the end:

```
myTeam.add(aTeam);
```

if absolutely it has to be an `array` rather than `ArrayList` then do this after your loop:

```
Team[] myArray=new Team[myTeam.size()];
myTeam.toArray(myArray);
```